# Python script reddit login failed/ Authorization failed

Tags: python, automation, reddit

me and some guys on Github opened an old project and are trying to resolve an old issue.
We are trying to make a bot for r/place using python and when we login it fails.

we tried making it retry logging in multiple times because someone said it happens randomly but it still didnt work.
this is the code we have

```
while True:
                        try:
                            client = requests.Session()
                            client.proxies = proxy.get_random_proxy(self, name)
                            client.headers.update(
                                {
                                    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36"
                                }
                            )

                            client.get("https://www.reddit.com")

                            r = client.get(
                                "https://www.reddit.com/login",
                                proxies=proxy.get_random_proxy(self, name),
                            )
                            login_get_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
                            csrf_token = login_get_soup.find(
                                "input", {"name": "csrf_token"}
                            )["value"]
                            data = {
                                "username": username,
                                "password": password,
                                "dest": "https://new.reddit.com/",
                                "csrf_token": csrf_token,
                                "otp": "",
                            }

                            r = client.post(
                                "https://www.reddit.com/login",
                                data=data,
                                proxies=proxy.get_random_proxy(self, name),
                            )
                            if r.text.find("INCORRECT_USERNAME_PASSWORD") != -1:
                                logger.warning("{} - Authorization failed! trying again in 10 seconds...", username)
                                time.sleep(10)
                                continue
                            break
                        except Exception:
                            logger.error(
                                "Failed to connect to websocket, trying again in 30 seconds..."
                            )
                            time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got past Authorization Failed by adding
"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
to the headers

> ```
>                        client.headers.update(
>                            {
>                                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36",
>                                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>                            }
>                        )
> ```